# Can Doxygen include a function declaration automatically?

Tags: c++, doxygen, dry, code-snippets

I'm writing a manual that links with Doxygen. In the manual I reference functions in the code. Ideally I'd like to tell the manual to simply include the function declaration as a code snippet rather than me copying and pasting it into the manual. I could do this via `\dontinclude` and `\line`; but I was wondering if there's a way to tell Doxygen to find the exact function I'm referring to and copy over its declaration to the current location of my manual file.

I'm imagining the following

MyClass.h

```
class MyClass
{

    /// \return The bar of the foo.
    /// \param foo The foo.
    double bar(double foo);

};
```

And reference it in my manual file:

```
...and you accomplish this by calling the object's `bar` member function:

\includedeclaration MyClass::bar(double)
```

Somehow a cross between `\copydoc` and `\snippet`.

Does such a thing exist? If not, can one hack it together somehow?